# Rails after_initialize all attributes show as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails application, I have a simple model names Business. I'm trying to access something during the after_initialize callback.

However ALL the attributes display nil. In the stacktrace, I can see that Business.new( params([:business]) ) contains the values passed inside to the form.

From the Business controller's 'create method'
[image]

Inside the Business model after_initialize
[image]

Is this a glitch, shouldn't the attributes be available by this point.

Comment: Second screenshot is useless; I'm old and cannot see. Text is better--cut and paste from the console instead.

Comment: I would but, there isn't anything to paste - ALL the attributes are nil. It's paused on the after_initialize method

Comment: Keep in mind that `after_initialize` is called whenever an activerecord object is instantiated. This is **not** just when you create a new `Business` object, but also when you retrieve one from the database (e.g. `business = Business.find(params[:id])` will call `after_initialize`). You should probably be finding a way to use either `before_create` or `after_create` instead.

Comment: Previously I was overwriting after_create, and the attributes were still nil. Good information about the after_initialize being called even after retrieval, though.

Comment: Are the individual params set after `after_initialize`? In other words, is it a mass initialization issue?

Comment: No they're set from the form, with the information that gets passed by params[:business] - which have valid values. Basically I'd like to use the data to do some geocoding, but i want to avoid waiting until after save and causing having to save twice.

Comment: @Onedayitwillmake..How can you say there is nothing to copy paste?..from the screenshot, I can see that you have set `attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude`..this means that **only** these attributes can be mass assigned..so you will have to add the other attributes to this list, in-order to mass assign these. I was able to spot this because I was able to see the code from the screenshot, thanks to my very good eyesight..but **you should really either copy-paste the code or use a bigger screenshot**..